# ROS Answers SE migration: ax2550 node

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been trying to run the ax2550_node from the ros ax2550 package found here  https://github.com/wjwwood/ax2550.git .

But i get an error which says

```
AX2550 connecting to port /dev/motor_controller
[ERROR] [1424892454.858165528]: Failed to connect to the AX2550: IO Exception (2): No such file or directory, file /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-serial-1.1.7-0raring-20141231-2116/src/impl/unix.cc, line 150.
[ INFO] [1424892454.858316111]: Will try to reconnect to the AX2550 in 5 seconds
```

I have tried changing the port permissions as suggested by this user (http://answers.ros.org/question/186558/ax2550-node-fails-to-connect-to-ax2550/) but to no avail. Could anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Update:

I have switched the usb-serial converter. I am now using Aten uc232-a. I am able to communicate with the controller via the roboteq roborun pc utility for windows 8. But somehow this node is unable to connect. I have tried assigning the serial port string("/dev/ttyUSB0") to the serial port parameter of the node using the following line : [**rosrun ax2550 ax2550_node _serial_port:="/dev/ttyUSB0"**] (&) [**rosrun ax2550 ax2550_node serial_port:="/dev/ttyUSB0"**] but it too has failed.

I dont know what iam doing wrong. Could anyone please guide me into the right direction. It is absolutely important for me to get this node working.

This is the output from "ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0":

**crwxrwxrwx 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb 28 04:14 /dev/ttyUSB0**

And when i run the node with the following command " rosrun ax2550 ax2550_node serial_port:="/dev/ttyUSB0" " i get the same error as specified earlier.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203794/ax2550-node/) by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-27**:
Please use the preview feature to review your question before posting - I had to reformat your question so that the full error message was visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output from the first error indicates that the device file it's trying to use (`/dev/motor_controller`) doesn't exist - not really surprising given that your motor controller is on a different port.

Unfortunately, you don't give enough information to answer your question well, such as what the node does when configured properly.

Please edit your question to include:

- The output from `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` (to verify that your serial port exists and has proper permissions)
- The output from running `rosrun ax2550 ax2550_node serial_port:="/dev/ttyUSB0"`

**UPDATE**

The ax2550 node uses parameters from the public namespace (NOT the node's private namespace). According to the [remapping arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) page, only private parameters can be set from the command line.

You should try setting the `serial_port` parameter using rosparam before starting the node:

```
rosparam set serial_port /dev/ttyUSB0
rosrun ax2550 ax2550_node
```

You **should not** have to change the node's source code in order to change the parameters.

You can also set the parameter and run the node via a launch file:

```
<launch>
  <param name="serial_port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
  <node pkg="ax2550" type="ax2550_node" name="ax2550_node"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2